How to file in UK small claims court from outside UK
I was intending to file suit against an airline ( Easyjet) in UK small claims court for compensation they are not paying up.
I was wondering, is it possible to do this without being physically present in the country and not having to pay for a lawyer?
The claim itself is about  £500 so appointing a lawyer would not be worth it.
I've already tried arbitration and it didn't work out.

Do they have any kind of business presence in your own country? If so you could try just filing against them there. Or if you are in the EU, there is a cross-EU small claims process so you could find the main business presence in the EU and file against them there. https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/dealing-with-customers/solving-disputes/european-small-claims-procedure/index_en.htm

@PaulJohnson this is very useful! I did not know of this!

@PaulJohnson But would it apply to the UK any more? After brexit?

No, the cross-EU thing won't let you sue them in the UK anymore, but e.g. if you live in Belgium and find they are doing business in France, you could use it to sue them in France. Just make sure that the subsidiary you sue is the same as the subsidiary you have a contract with. Suing the wrong company is a common mistake in these circumstances. I don't know about Easyjet's internal structure. Look carefully at your receipts to find out.
